# Open file which do not have standard name

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose, we have one folder with only one macro file and every day we are saving excel file in the same folder received via mail. However, filename every day will get changed. I mean to say what ever file we are getting through mail do not have a standard name. Now, we have two files in the same folder.

Can we open another file which we have saved with some random name available in the same folder using a macro? Here, the name of another file is not standard. Additionally, after running a macro, we also want to delete that file.

Comment: How can the file be recognised? Is it the newest one in that directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the filename of the **newest** file within a directory by this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GetNewestFilename()
    Dim searchDirectory As String
    Dim searchPattern As String
    Dim currentFilename As String
    Dim NewestFilename As String
    Dim NewestFiledate As Date

    searchDirectory = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    searchPattern = "*.xl*"

    currentFilename = Dir(searchDirectory & searchPattern, 0)
    If currentFilename <> "" Then
        NewestFilename = currentFilename
        NewestFiledate = FileDateTime(searchDirectory & currentFilename)
        Do While currentFilename <> ""
            If FileDateTime(searchDirectory & currentFilename) > NewestFiledate Then
                 NewestFilename = currentFilename
                 NewestFiledate = FileDateTime(searchDirectory & currentFilename)
            End If
            currentFilename = Dir
        Loop
    End If
    MsgBox NewestFilename

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(searchDirectory & NewestFilename)
    ' do something
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wb = Nothing

    ' Kill searchDirectory & NewestFilename ' Delete the file

End Sub
```

Comment: Fine :) Please do me a favor and mark the checkbox beneath my answer (reason is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))